# Boolean method to check value of an Web element

Tags: java, selenium

I need to test a dynamic Web Element using Selenium that will change its value after some time(back-end dependent). So, I built a boolean method that returns true if the web element has the value I need and false if that value is never retrieved. I want to check for value change at some intervals (thus, the Thread.sleep between page refreshes). My code always returns true, what am I doing wrong?

```
public boolean checkStatus() throws InterruptedException {

    for(int i=0; i<2;) {
        if (!serviceStatus.serviceElement().equals("LIVE")) {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            theBrowser.navigate().refresh();
            i++;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The method is used in the main test on the following assert:

```
    Ensure.that(checkStatus()).isTrue();
```

Comment: How and where do you define `serviceStatus.serviceElement()`? If it s a page object field it might be cached so that the value doesn't get re-lookup.

Answer (score 0):

I presume serviceElement() is the Webelement,you have to get the text for the element using getText() method and compare with the string you desire("LIVE") in this scenario.You seems to be comparing an Webelement with String here. Below should work if i understood the requirement correctly.

```
public boolean checkStatus() throws InterruptedException {
      boolean isMatching = false;
    for(int i=0; i<2;) {
        if (!serviceStatus.serviceElement().getText().equals("LIVE")) {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            theBrowser.navigate().refresh();
            i++;
            isMatching = false;
            break;

        }else{
            isMatching = true;
        }
    }
    return isMatching;
}
```

Comment: serviceElement() is already defined as String when I retrieved the WebElement into Selenium. I tested this by adding this line of code after Thread.sleep : System.out.println(serviceStatus.serviceElement()) which returns current value "DOWN"

Comment: I have modified the code to exit for loop when not matched just to check if the values are appropriate against each variable you are trying to compare. Could you try to debug the value of serviceStatus.serviceElement() just before the "if". Possibly each time the code gets in "if" when i=0 refresh() method sets the value of serviceElement() to "LIVE" and in next iteration of for loop it goes directly to "else"